# Error copying file from app bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io, nsfilemanager

I used the FireFox add-on SQLite Manager, created a database, which saved to my desktop as "DB.sqlite". I copied the file into my supporting files for the project. But when I run the app, immediately I get the error

> **"Assertion failure in -[AppDelegate copyDatabaseIfNeeded], /Users/Mac/Desktop/Note/Note/AppDelegate.m:32 2014-08-19 23:38:02.830
>   Note[28309:60b]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to create writable
>   database file with message 'The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (Cocoa error 4.)'.' First throw call stack: "...

Here is the App Delegate Code where the error takes place

```
-(void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if (!success)
    {
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[ [NSBundle mainBundle
                                       ] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB.sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
        if (!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);

    }
}
```

I am very new to Sqlite, so I maybe I didn't create a database correctly in the FireFox Sqlite manager, or maybe I didn't "properly" copy the .sqlite file in? (I did check the target membership in the sqlite and it correctly has my project selected. Also, the .sqlite file names all match up perfectly.)

Comment: It's got nothing to do with sqlite, as such, it's a file copy error.  Please check the source and destination path are valid and that the prototype database has been copied into the app bundle and matches the source path.

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? Sorry, I just don't fully understand the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, you can't write a file in your app's bundle. The entire bundle is read-only.
   You should create the database (sqlite file) inside the NSDocumentDirectory in order to work on it.

Please visit site below for tutorial:
   http://objectivecwithsuraj.blogspot.in/2012/10/database-implementation-using-sqlite-in.html

Sample Code:
   https://github.com/surajwebo/SQLite-Demonstration-

Comment: The OP has a file copy issue and the issue has nothing to do with sqlite.

Comment: I have edited my answer according to the issue raised by #Michael Chen

Comment: But you've missed the fact that's the OP is copying *from* the app bundle, not *to* it.

Comment: Please check the question #trojanfoe. As mentioned "I copied the file into my supporting files for the project" which means #Michael Chen is copying the sqlite file from Desktop to Main Bundle -> Supporting Files.

Comment: By that I assumed the OP meant he copied it within Xcode.

Comment: To clarify, the .sqlite is on my desktop and I just copied it, and pasted it directly into supporting files.

Comment: Please help! I still have no idea who to listen to or what to do!

Comment: Copy that sqlite file in your applications document directory. I will say you must go through the sample code: https://github.com/surajwebo/SQLite-Demonstration-